# Analysis of the word

Tags: british-english

What's wrong with the sentence:

> Put the rest of the water at the back of the door in the kitchen

Comment: The preposition *at*; doors don't really have *at*s, they have *by*s. You could justify that the *backs of doors* have *at*s, but it's still weird.

Comment: Technically there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @DanBron - So one shouldn't say "I'll be waiting at the third door from the left"?

Comment: There, it's position along the hall (left-right) which has the *at*, not the door.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

Put the rest of the water **behind** the door in the kitchen

because for a door we think of *behind* or *in front of* rather than *at the back of*.

I wondered if *at the back of* would be more common in US-English - but we would say in British-English *at the back of the queue* - or *at the back of the cupboard* -

I suppose *at the back of* works for a container like a cupboard or a wardrobe that you can get inside, but for a door you are either in front or behind.- you could also be by a door as in the comment of Dan Bron

Comment: No, Tom, it's wrong in the U.S., too.  Here, we also say "at the back (or end) of the line" (most understand "queue" but don't use it) but things go behind a door.